# Any reason to use std::thread over std::jthread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

So C++20 has introduced [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) which, as I understand it, is just better than [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) in every regard. So apart from the usual limitations like availabilty of C++20, quality of implementation, interaction with libraries, ...  - is there any scenario where `std::thread` is the better choice?

Comment: more is not always better https://godbolt.org/z/n3xTb6

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I would argue the the cost of more, especially for a complex object such as a thread, does not lie in the 8 additional bytes. Your point is good, but the demonstration not so much :)

Comment: jthread is designed to make things more "client friendly."  it takes the "oh I need to join my thread" and removes that concern from the client, making it harder to implement bad designs.

Comment: @spectras agree. I admit that I took the "better in every regard" too literally and just used the first counter-example I could find. If quality of implementation is put aside then `std::thread` could use 16 as well and my point is moot.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 No you're absolutely right. The size difference comes from the stop source. I would not put that under implementation quality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::jthread` is like a `std::thread` which owns a `std::stop_source`.

C++ is a language heavily built around the concept of not having to pay for what you don't use.

So: if you don't need a `std::stop_source`, you should prefer a `std::thread` so that you don't pay for one.

Even if you do need one, you still might prefer not to use `std::jthread` and keep your stop source elsewhere, for the same reason that you might use `boost::intrusive_ptr` rather than `std::shared_ptr`, i.e. being able to manage data locality.